# Configuration for Stripping Debugging Symbols in Visual Studio for mac

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I need to remove the debugging symbols from the IPA file.
I enabled the `Strip native debugging symbols` under `Project Options -> iOS Build`.

I used the nm command to check and still I am getting symbol information from the iPA file.

I tried the same by creating a native project in XCode and stripped the debug symbols using the following configuration

```
Deployment Post processing -> YES
Strip Linked Product -> YES
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy -> YES
Generate Debug Symbols -> NO
Debug Information Format -> DWARF
```

After archiving the XCode project, I used the nm command and I am not getting any symbol information.

Is there any other configuration in visual studio for mac to perform this?

**Update:**
Also tried adding `--dsym=false` in the Additional *mtouch* Arguments but I am unable to archive the file and getting the following error

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1005,3): error MSB3375: The file "bin/iPhone/Release/AppName.iOS.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist" does not exist.

Comment: If you adding `--dsym=false` in the Additional mtouch Arguments, you have to uncheck `Strip native debugging symbols`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tired archiving by only adding `--dsym=false` with `Strip native debugging symbols` unchecked. Now I am able to archive but it is having symbol information.

Comment: What symbol information did you find?

Comment: @Siddharth Did you got any solution for this?